# Why does the screenshot show just white when I'm trying to take a screenshot of my app programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, screenshot

On my app, I have a view which holds a camera. I want to take a screenshot of this view which holds the camera. However when I do this with the following code:

```
let layer = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.layer
let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);

layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)
```

the screenshot which was saved to photos is just blank and doesn't show the camera view.

Comment: I believe that the camera view doesn't use `CALayer`. You have to use the native way of taking pictures.

Comment: okay thanks, however when I try to do this using this code - var cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)   "kCGRenderingIntentDEfault" has an error "unresolved identifier" do you have any idea of how to fix this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Render and capture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html) an `UIView` named `view`:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, 0.0)
view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Remember that `UIWindow` is a view too.
You can test in the simulator saving to the desktop with this function:

```
public func saveImageToDesktop(image : UIImage, name : String)
{
    let basePath = NSString(string: "~/Desktop").stringByExpandingTildeInPath
    let path = "\(basePath)/\(name).png"
    UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
}
```